# How to find all users on Exchange server from a particular OU?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, exchange-server

I need to get a report of all users on an Exchange server who are located at one particular OU in Active Directory.  Is there a way to do this with Powershell or VBS?

Thanks

Comment: You want to get all mailbox users located at a particular OU? What Exchange version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit 'OU=test1,DC=domain,DC=com'
```

Answer (score 0):

The PS cmdlet will work for versions of Exchange 2007 and later.
Here is how you'd extract the list and dump it in a text file. I've added the -IgnoreDefaultScope handle so that you're able to extract the list even though the OU in question is in a subdomain.

```
Get-Mailbox -IgnoreDefaultScope -ResultSize Unlimited -OrganizationalUnit 'OU=Staff Leavers,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com' > C:\SysMgr\LeaverMailboxes.txt
```